# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: no filter named 'split'

Tags: json, split, ansible

My ansible script looks like,

```
- name: get dataset id
  set_fact : 
    dataset_ID: "{{ABC.json.datasets | json_query(query) | map('split', '/') | map(attribute=5) | list | first}}"
  vars:
    query: "[?displayName == 'My_dataset'].name"
```

it gives me this error

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: no filter named 'split'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
```

Not sure what's happening here. I mean the script was working fine before and when I ran this in new VM  it throws this error. Any idea regrading this?

Comment: How are you running the playbook? Are you running it *on* the remote host, or are you running it on a control host and having Ansible connect to the remote host?

Answer (score 9):

The `split` filter wasn't added until [February 2021](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/d3441bc313bfca1771d17c9af14b95626b073d0b). I think that means if you're running anything earlier than Ansible 2.11 you won't have it.