# Rewriting the yaml variable (ansible)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a variable:

```
"result":[
            {
            "item": "192.168.0.1",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "d",
                "e",
              ]
             },
            {
            "item": "192.168.0.2",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "aa",
                "bb",
                "cc",
               ]
            }
         ]
```

I want to get the following variable:

```
"result":[
            {
            "item": [
                "192.168.0.1",
                "192.168.0.1",
                "192.168.0.1",
                "192.168.0.1",
                "192.168.0.1",
               ]
            "stdout_lines": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "d",
                "e",
              ]
             },
            {
            "item": [
                "192.168.0.2",
                "192.168.0.2",
                "192.168.0.2",
               ]
            "stdout_lines": [
                "aa",
                "bb",
                "cc",
               ]
            }
         ]
```

That is, I need the value of "item" to be repeated as many times as the values in "stdout_lines". The values of "stdout_lines" always change, "stdout_lines" can have a different number of values.

How can I do this?

Comment: I understand your use case that you like to cross join, get the cartesian product of two tables.

Comment: If you can add (edit the question) some context on what you are trying to do with the original data structure, and why you want it restructured will be useful. Also, if you've tried something to this end, please include those details too.

Comment: How to do it? This is the first time I've come across this.

Comment: Why do you need the lists? What do you want to do with them? There might be a more efficient approach.

Comment: I need this for further writing to the mysql table. For example, the ip address 192.168.0.1 belongs to "a,b,c", and I need to make three entries in the table: 192.168.0.1 | a, 192.168.0.1 |b, 192.168.0.1 \c and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _tmp: "{{ _tmp|d([]) + [item|combine({'item': _items.split()})] }}"
      loop: "{{ result }}"
      vars:
        _count: "{{ item.stdout_lines|length }}"
        _item: "{{ item.item }} "
        _items: "{{ _item * _count|int }}"
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ _tmp }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
result:
  - item:
    - 192.168.0.1
    - 192.168.0.1
    - 192.168.0.1
    - 192.168.0.1
    - 192.168.0.1
    stdout_lines:
    - a
    - b
    - c
    - d
    - e
  - item:
    - 192.168.0.2
    - 192.168.0.2
    - 192.168.0.2
    stdout_lines:
    - aa
    - bb
    - cc
```

Comment: Seems to be a better approach than my own "half" solution [`with_cartesian`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/cartesian_lookup.html). I just like to note that the `split` filter is available as of Ansible v2.11, according my [Error: no filter named 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870999/6771046).

Comment: *split* can be used as a method here.